# MVC3 Table Storage and Account Validation examples

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

Has anyone seen any good examples of how I can use MVC3 and TableStorage with Azure account validation. Everything I look at seems to still be ASP.net or just a very basic example. I am surprised the Windows Azure site doesn't include more MVC examples.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean here. Do you want to see an example of an MVC3 application using Table Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you need and what do you mean by "Azure account validation"?
As for Storage - the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll is a single assembly with common wrapping types around the Storage API. There is nothing technology specific. You can use storage client in any .NET assembly (well, not in Silverlight directly). But all operations over Windows Azure Storage are performed the same way regardless of whether it is a ASP.NET application, or MVC site, or WPF application, or WinForms application. So you may take the Azure Storage related code in your MVC application and use it as is. You just need an MVC3 Web Role, which is a standard and available project template since Windows Azure SDK 1.5.